# Adam optimizer - ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow 2.3

The code below

```
import  tensorflow as tf

y_N= tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.],name="dd")

@tf.function
def loss():
    return -tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=tf.math.log(y_N), axis=0))

@tf.function
def run():
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5).minimize(loss, var_list=[y_N])

run()
```

gives exception

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

Problem looks like `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5).minimize(loss, var_list=[y_N])` creates new variable on > first call, while using `@tf.function`. If must wrap it under `@tf.function`, how should I modify it? (in real case `run()` is a much bigger function)

Comment: Looks like there's a bug for this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42183

Answer (score 3):

I think it's probably not about the optimizer. Because of using **function decorator**, I think we need to enable the eager execution of `tf.functions` as follows. [Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly)

```py
import  tensorflow as tf
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

y_N= tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.],name="dd")

@tf.function
def loss():
    return -tf.reduce_mean(
        input_tensor=tf.reduce_sum(
            input_tensor=tf.math.log(y_N), axis=0
        )
    )

@tf.function
def run():
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5).minimize(loss, var_list=[y_N])

run()
print(y_N)
```

```
<tf.Variable 'dd:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, 
numpy=array([1.5000134, 2.5000117, 3.5000103], dtype=float32)>
```

---

### Update

The above code would run on eager mode with the cost of performance. To run it on graph mode, first, create instance of `optimizers.Adam` class and use class method afterwards as follows:

```
y_N = tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.],name="dd")
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5)

@tf.function
def loss():
    return -tf.reduce_mean(
        input_tensor=tf.reduce_sum(
            input_tensor=tf.math.log(y_N), axis=0
        )
    )

@tf.function
def run():
    opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[y_N])

run()
print(y_N)
```

```
<tf.Variable 'dd:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, 
numpy=array([1.4999985, 2.499997 , 3.4999952], dtype=float32)>
```

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167295/valueerror-tf-function-decorated-function-tried-to-create-variables-on-non-firs) for similar details.

Comment: sure, let's loose 90% of performances of TF in a single line of code

Comment: I've updated the code with a solutions that may work on graph mode. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I won't be able to provide you all the explanations you might be looking for, as the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) for `@tf.function` is somewhat complex, but in my experience building neural nets with Tensorflow, only the subparts of the "running" process must be decorated with `@tf.function`, and this part must be within `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:`. Your code works if I implement it that way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_N= tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.], name="dd")

@tf.function
def loss():
    return -tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.reduce_sum(
                           input_tensor=tf.math.log(y_N), axis=0))

def run():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5).minimize(loss, var_list=[y_N])

run()

print(y_N)
```

```
<tf.Variable 'dd:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.4999985, 2.499997 , 
    3.4999952], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: I think gradient tape already included, as from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam#minimize -  under minimize method: "this method simply computes gradient using tf.GradientTape and calls apply_gradients(). If you want to process the gradient before applying then call tf.GradientTape and apply_gradients() explicitly instead of using this function."

Comment: it also says _If you want to process the gradient before applying then call tf.GradientTape and apply_gradients() explicitly instead of using this function._

Comment: Would that paragraph help in any way in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that  after calling `minimize` function, it will create an `iter` variable, by calling `self.iterations` once.
(This happens in `tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py`)

Subsequent call of the `self.iterations` will not create a new variable -
as `iter` has already been created.

Therefore, by calling to make it work, we need to create the `optimizer` once outside, and pass it in to @tf.function. It will still create variables in `minimize` function, but it will only do it once since we don't repeatedly create the Adam model.

```
import  tensorflow as tf

y_N= tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.],name="dd")

@tf.function
def loss():
    return -tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=tf.math.log(y_N), axis=0))

@tf.function
def run(adam):
    adam.minimize(loss, var_list=[y_N])


adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5)

run(adam)
```