# ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a model written with **Model Subclassing API** in `tensorflow 2`. It contains a custom layer. The issue is, in the custom layer, I need to send the channel number of the input tensor to a `Conv2D` layer in the runtime. Please, see the code below:

**Custom Layer**

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

class AuxNet(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ratio=8):
        super(AuxNet, self).__init__()
        self.ratio = ratio
        self.avg = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.max = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()

    def call(self, inputs):
        avg = self.avg(inputs)
        max = self.max(inputs)
        avg = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 1, avg.shape[1]))(avg)  
        max = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 1, max.shape[1]))(max)   
        
        # ALERT ---------------------
        input_shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
        _, h, w, channels = input_shape
        
        conv1a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=1, 
                         strides=1, padding='same',use_bias=True, 
                         activation=tf.nn.relu)(avg)
        
        conv1b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=1, strides=1, 
                                    padding='same',use_bias=True, 
                                    activation=tf.nn.relu)(max)
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(conv1a + conv1b)
```

The whole model

```py
class Net(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.base  = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(124, 3, 1)
        self.gap   = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.aux   = AuxNet() # init the custom layer
        self.dense  = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.out   = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    
    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x  = self.base(input_tensor)
        
        # Using custom layer on the input tensor
        aux = self.aux(x)*x

        x = self.gap(aux)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return self.out(x)
```

As you can see, the `AuxNet` classes contain the `Conv2D` layer with the filter size of the `channel` of its input. And the input is nothing but the input of the model class, the `Net`. When initializing the custom layer in the model class, I couldn't set the channel number of its `Conv2D` layer. So, what I did here, I compute the channel number for this `Conv2D` in the `call` method of the `AuxNet` layer, which I believe is bad practice.

This issue brings the runtime problem. I couldn't compile the `Model` class in a graph mode but a force to enable eager mode.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# train set / data 
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255

# train set / target 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)

model = Net((32, 32, 3))

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) # < ----------------

model.compile(
          loss      = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics   = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
# fit 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=1)
```

It works, but **very slow** training. However, without this, the following error occurs,

> **ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.**

Any workaround for no need to enable eager mode? How can I efficiently pass the required argument to this custom layer? In that case, I don't have to compute channel depth in the `call` method.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. As it stands, your model is creating new convolution layers each time it is called (i.e. each training iteration), which makes no sense and makes training impossible (since variables are reset each time). I think you might want to read up on how to create custom layers, e.g. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) or [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models). In particular, look at how variables are created in the `build` method.

Comment: It's a toy demonstration of the main task. However, thanks for the pointer. I will carefully read the document. :)

Comment: @xdurch0 It solves. Thank you. : xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to look at **how to define built-in layers inside the custom layer**. It's advised that all layers should initialize the `__init__` method. But we needed the `channel` depth of the unknown tensor and based on that value the `filters` number would be set. However, in the `build` method we can do that easily.

```py
class AuxNet(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ratio=8):
        super(AuxNet, self).__init__()
        self.ratio = ratio
        self.avg = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.max = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape[-1], 
                               kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same',
                               use_bias=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape[-1], 
                                               kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same',
                                               use_bias=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        
        super(AuxNet, self).build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        avg = self.avg(inputs)
        max = self.max(inputs)
        avg = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 1, avg.shape[1]))(avg)  
        max = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 1, max.shape[1]))(max)   
        
        conv1a = self.conv1(avg)
        conv1b = self.conv2(max)
        
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(conv1a + conv1b)
```